# Grails multiple select

Tags: grails, user-registration

I'm implementing a registration form in Grails with a bit of Ajax.  My goal is to display a radio group of three options and based on the selection, the relevant domain fields will appear below.

I have three domain objects: an User, Donor and Teacher.  A User can be a Donor, Teacher or both, thus the reason for a wrapping object.

All the examples I've seen with multiple selections from a list or radio group deal with different instances of the same domain class.  Is it possible to do this with multiple domain objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 templates for each domain class and based on the value of your select or radio button render the correspondent template.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [AJAX Driven SELECTs in GSP](http://grails.org/AJAX-Driven+SELECTs+in+GSP)

Maybe can solve your issue